# How do I plot loglikelihood functions of the Cauchy distribution in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, maximum-likelihood

I need to determine whether or not there is always a unique root of the log-likelihood equation l'(x,0)=0 for different samples sizes of the Cauchy distribution.

But I am unsure about how to actually define the log-likelihood function R and about actually being able to plot these graphs. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

"The" Cauchy distribution is a misnomer: it is intended to refer to a *family* of distributions.

As an example, let's consider the location-scale family of distributions whose PDFs are given by

$$f(x; \mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\pi \sigma}\left(1 + \left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)^{-1}.$$

(The special case $\mu=0, \sigma=1$ is the Cauchy distribution.)

By definition, the log likelihood $\Lambda$ of a batch of $n$ data $(x_i)$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$, is the logarithm of their probability, *assuming* the data are independently and identically distributed according to $f(x;\mu,\sigma)$.  The independence assumption implies the probability is the product of individual probabilities, whence

$$\Lambda(\mu,\sigma; x) = \log \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;\mu,\sigma) = -\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(1 + \left(\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right) -n \log(\pi \sigma).$$

This must be plotted as the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ vary.

In `R`, use `contour` or `filled.contour` to make such a plot.  As with many scale families, it will be clearer to plot $\sigma$ on a logarithmic scale.  So, we estimate a reasonable range for $\mu$, a reasonable range for $\log(\sigma)$, divide those ranges into little pieces, evaluate  $\Lambda$ at each possible combination of those pieces, and contour the results:

```
logLikelihood <- function(median, scale, x) {
  -sum(log(1 + ((x-median)/scale)^2)) - length(x)*log(pi*scale)
}

set.seed(17)
data <- rnorm(3) # Sample data (not drawn from a Cauchy distribution!)

medians <- seq(-3, 3, 1/50)                       # Range of medians to plot
scales <- seq(-1.5, 2, 1/50)                      # Range of (log) scales to plot
u <- as.matrix(expand.grid(medians, exp(scales))) # Points to evaluate
z <- matrix(apply(u, 1, function(v) logLikelihood(v[1], v[2], data)),
       nrow = length(medians))                    # Values of Lambda on the grid
filled.contour(medians, scales, z, color.palette=terrain.colors, 
               xlab="Median", ylab="Log(scale)",
               main="Cauchy Log Likelihood")
```

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: Thank you for that! However, I need to plot log-likelihood functions for Cauchy(0,1) with different sample sizes, this helps me visualise the whole concept but would anyone be able to elaborate on how to plot the curves of l(x,theta) please?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your questions, Vivek: the code already answers them. Different sample sizes are obtained by varying `data`; the curves of the log likelihood are apparent as the contours in this plot. I also do not understand what you mean by "log-likelihood functions for Cauchy(0,1)," because this is not consistent with what likelihood means: the likelihood is a *number* for any particular distribution, such as Cauchy(0,1), not a function: it is the probability of the data for that distribution.